# set timezone mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone

I want to set timezone in mysql from default timezone ('los angles') to  my own timezone ('asia/jakart'). I have been change the timezone using query ->

```
SET GLOBAL TIME_ZONE = 'ASIA/JAKARTA'
```

The timezone was change if i using the query above. but if i restart mysql, the timezone is back to default timezone(los angels).

How to make the timezone changed permanent to asia/jakarta?

Answer (score 2):

Put the following in your mysql server configuration (e.g. my.cnf)

```
default-time-zone=Asia/Jakarta
```

Please check the [doc here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html)

Comment: Someone downvoted the answer. Please do me a favor by telling what was wrong.

Comment: you should use underscores (_) for the syntax (e.g. default_time_zone=Asia/Jakarta). Otherwise it won't work. See Azmat-karim answer below

Answer (score 1):

**In /etc/mysql/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default_time_zone=Asia/Jakarta
```

Remember to use underscores _